# Dealing with super

Tags: java

I don't fully understand the topic and how that works. I wrote a code sample, does it look correct? Because when i ran it, it kept giving me error.

```
class team {
    public team(String[] name, String[] lastname, int year) {
    private String[] name;
    private String[] lastname;
    private int[] year;
}

public class Player extends team {
    Patrolman(String first, String last, int y){
        super(first,last,y);
        name first = new name{Road};
        lastname last = new lastname{Runner};
        year y = new year{5};
}
```

Comment: would you tell us what error you get?

Comment: Maybe you could describe the error?  We can't actually see your screen from here.  Also, this code doesn't compile.  For reasons entirely unrelated to `super`.

Comment: You need to learn the basic java syntax first

Comment: Are you sure you *ran* it, or did you just try to *compile* it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you have is not with the super - you can't have private fields declared inside the constructor. Class fields should be declared in the class scope, not inside the constructor or any other method.

it should look like:

```
class team {
  private String[] name;
  private String[] lastname;
  private int[] year;
  public team(String[] name, String[] lastname, int year) {
    name = name;
    lastname = lastname;
    year = year;      
  }

...
...
...
```

also, I don't understand what you mean in the Patrolman constructor:

```
name first = new name{Road};
lastname last = new lastname{Runner};
year y = new year{5};
```

this is not java syntax. I guess you mean:

```
String[] name = {'Road'};
String[] lastname = {'Runner'};
int year = 5;
```

but since calling the super should be the first thing in the sub class's constructor, you should do:

```
Patrolman(String first, String last, int y) {
  super({first},{last},y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing the error you're getting I'm going to guess that it's due to the `Patrolman` constructor in a `Player` class

Try this instead

```
public class Team {
   private String[] name;
   private String[] lastname;
   private int[] year;

   public Team(String first, String last, String y) {
      name = first.getBytes();
      lastname = last.getBytes();
      year = y.getBytes();
   }
}

public class Player extends Team {
    Player(String first, String last, int y) {
        super(first,last,y);
    }
}
```

Since you pass `first`, `last`, and `y` into the `super` you probably do not need to do anything with them in the `Player` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code.

1. You're declaring new variables in your constructor. those variables aren't going to store anything. They need to be declared outside the constructor and then initialized inside of the constructor from the arguments passed in.
2. In your subclass you call super() but you are passing in Strings while the superclass constructor accepts String arrays
3. In your subclasses constructor you try to set a value to `name` but the variable doesn't appear to be instantiated in your subclass. In your superclass it is created (inside the constructor so it needs to be moved out) as a private variable and therefor can't be accessed directly in the subclass. You need to either use a public/protected getter method or make the variable itself public or protected.
4. The variable `name` should be a String and not its own object. It doesn't need to be declared with the `new` keyword because that is only used when creating objects. Simply doing `String name = variableName;` would work. The same is true for all your variables in the subclass constructor

Answer (score 0):

While I can't help too much because you don't provide an error message, I can explain super.

The `super` keyword in Java is a reference to a derived class's parent class. It's main use is when you are trying to call the version of a method or constructor of the parent class.

For example, if we have a base class A, and a derived class B such as this...

```
public class A
{
    public A()
    {
        //Constructor
    }

    public void display()
    {
        System.out.println("TEST");
    }
}

public class B extends A
{
    public B()
    {
        super();
    }

    public void display()
    {
        super.display();
    }
}
```

The call to `super()` in the constructor of the `B class` will call the `A class` constructor to be executed.

Similarly with overridden methods between classes of the same family, you can call `super` with the parent's method to be executed like I have written in the overridden `display` method.

Hope that helps!